# Xamarin.iOS application freezes on iOS 13

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, freeze, ios13

I have Xamarin Native (iOS/Android) application. The application works without problems on iOS 12 and below. If you run the application on the device with iOS 13, then it starts to freeze for unknown reasons and this bug doesn't have clear steps to reproduce, it occurs on different screens.

This is stacktrace from Visual Studio for Mac

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
    0x1003ea775 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1003de6b5 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_handle_native_crash
    0x1003f19f1 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x10790bb1d - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : _sigtramp
    0x111ab5e38 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView
    0x122711c6b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZNSt3__110shared_ptrIN3ggl6BufferEED2Ev
    0x1227397f3 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZNSt3__110shared_ptrIN3ggl12ConstantDataEED2Ev
    0x122c98778 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZNSt3__113__vector_baseIN3ggl19ConstantDataElementEN3geo12StdAllocatorIS2_NS1_9AllocatorEEEED2Ev
    0x122c9850c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZN3ggl13PipelineSetupD2Ev
    0x1227b3d24 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZN3ggl6Circle17FillPipelineSetupD0Ev
    0x122b3059d - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZNSt3__120__shared_ptr_emplaceIN2md23CircleOverlayRenderableENS_9allocatorIS2_EEE16__on_zero_sharedEv
    0x12281c40b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : _ZNSt3__110shared_ptrIN2md23CircleOverlayRenderableEED2Ev
    0x1068eff02 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class
    0x1068ff3c9 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : objc_destructInstance
    0x10690598f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : -[NSObject dealloc]
    0x122b2eb22 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VectorKit.framework/VectorKit : -[VKVectorOverlayCircle dealloc]
    0x106906116 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
    0x1068eff02 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZL27object_cxxDestructFromClassP11objc_objectP10objc_class
    0x1068ff3c9 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : objc_destructInstance
    0x10690598f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : -[NSObject dealloc]
    0x101d63e52 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit : -[MKOverlayRenderer dealloc]
    0x101d63d9b - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit : -[MKOverlayPathRenderer dealloc]
    0x106906116 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib : _ZN11objc_object17sidetable_releaseEb
    0x100640abd - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : xamarin_release_managed_ref
    0x12a596bbc - Unknown
    0x132b427b9 - Unknown
    0x1003f4dd5 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1005210e7 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x100524a6e - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x10064a822 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x10065257b - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
    0x100653782 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : xamarin_x86_64_common_trampoline
    0x100dd0d10 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : __NSThreadPerformPerform
    0x105b2e271 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION_
    0x105b2e19c - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSource0
    0x105b2d974 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    0x105b2867f - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : __CFRunLoopRun
    0x105b27e66 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x10ca74bb0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x110d41dd0 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x12a4abae2 - Unknown
    0x12a4ab833 - Unknown
    0x12940fae3 - Unknown
    0x12940ffb9 - Unknown
    0x1003f4dd5 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1005210e7 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x10052756c - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x100354a22 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x100651a1e - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : xamarin_main
    0x10030f4a7 - /Users/konstya.gerasymenko/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/95B31EC1-0A24-474B-858E-024385DE8FFA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/216D0956-E0D0-40AD-A6F0-838AE3A49926/MyAppiOS.app/MyAppiOS : main
    0x107528d29 - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : start
    0x3 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x122cb448d):0x122cb447d  48 8b 7f 08 48 85 ff 74 13 48 8b 73 10 48 8b 07  H...H..t.H.s.H..
0x122cb448d  ff 50 10 b8 ad ba ad de 48 89 43 10 48 83 c4 08  .P......H.C.H...
0x122cb449d  5b 5d c3 55 48 89 e5 53 50 48 89 fb 48 8d 05 90  [].UH..SPH..H...
0x122cb44ad  f2 29 00 48 89 07 48 8b 7f 08 48 85 ff 74 0a 48  .).H..H...H..t.H

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at Foundation.NSObject:xamarin_release_managed_ref <0x000cb>
      at Foundation.NSObject:ReleaseManagedRef <0x0007a>
      at NSObject_Disposer:Drain <0x00392>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x001a8>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x00251>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x000b2>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00132>
      at MyApp.iOS.Application:Main <0x00202>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object <0x001a8>
=================================================================
```

The first thing that comes to mind is problems with disposing of some NSObject (possible some memory leak), but it is very strange that this problem doesn't reproduce on slower devices with a lower version of iOS.

Please tell me if anyone else has encountered a similar problem. Are there any assumptions about the source of the problem?

Comment: Could you change the Log to Diagnostic verbosity and share more of your stacktrace? Also, have you tried to place an Exception Catchpoint? Is this a problem on Simulator and Device?

Comment: @Saamer, I changed Log to Diagnostic verbosity but stacktrace for current issue the same as with Normal verbosity. This bug is reproducible on Devices and iOS simulators with iOS 13. What do you mean when asking about Exception Catchpoint? Actually I set Exception Catchpoint around the all UIApplication.Main(...), where I usually catch all the exceptions that occur in the application, but this bug doesn't crash the app but freezes and I can see stacktrace I indicated above.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample here with this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not, because it is not known which code leads to this issue. This bug is reproduced on different screens of the application. At the moment, I strive to understand what code leads to this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of this bug and it related to disposing of MKMapView. On few screens where I display map I added Overlays (MKCircle) and OverlayRenderers (MKCircleRenderer) to the map and references to those Overlays and OverlayRenderers contains in private variables. So the main problem was is that during of screen disposing was disposed only map (MKMapView) object but not private variables with references to map Overlay and OverlayRenderer. After adding explicit disposing of this variables this bug has disappeared.

Comment: Hi Kostya, I'm having the same problem and I suspect it's because of a MKMapView as well. Can you share: 

1) how did you pinpoint the cause
2) How exactly did you do the explicit disposing? I am using:
mapView.Overlays.ToList().ForEach(mapView.RemoveOverlay);
and it's not solving the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would like to know that as well. The same is happening to me. Thanks!

Comment: Check this link to see code example: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/171095/xamarin-ios-application-freezes-on-ios-13